Loading all items in searchable select from start or while typing?
I have an interesting case where I have a form for adding data to a database. I am using Next.js and a PostgreSQL database for reference. There are two select fields (where I use the react-select library) where I can search the database for entries. Nothing special about this, but as soon as I start type it will search the database for matching values.
To be specific, the select field is searching through thousands of airports.
However, I don't want to load the dropdown with an array of thousands of airports on load (I feel that would be unnecessary?), but when you start typing it fetches from the database. Is it worse to query the database while typing or just querying the whole table from the start?
Second of all, I have this functionality that the select field can be auto-populated based on input from another field. In this case it would be best just to load everything into the select field from the start.
How would you solve this issue? Not sure what is the best practice here.

I would recommend that you load the top 100 records beforehand. Then, the top 100 matching records are retrieved while the user is typing. Also, we should apply debounce on search input to reduce the database calls.

I was on the verge of typing exactly the same thing @AamirDalal said.

For your second scenario, where you are auto-populating input based on other input, you should make a separate database call that only loads the specific record that needs to be populated.
